# jQuery animate chaining change animation speed at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to make a few translations of an object using the jQuery animate method.

Consider the following snippet:

```
$(function() {
$('#camion').animate({ top: 120, left: 180}, $('#vitesse').val());
$('#camion').animate({ top: 180, left: 180}, $('#vitesse').val());
$('#camion').animate({ top: 220, left: 180}, $('#vitesse').val());
$('#camion').animate({ top: 330, left: 180}, $('#vitesse').val());
});
```

Now, $('#vitesse') is a textbox. The $('#camion') element is an image that needs to be animated to 4 checkpoint in the page. What I would like to achieve is to be able to change the speed of the animation after each checkpoint. So if I update the textbox between the 1st and 2nd animation, the 3rd is going to be quicker or slower depending on what I write.

I've tried with `$.fn.delay`  and `setTimeout` but was not quite able to do that, it still uses the first value in the textbox and never use anything else.

How should I be able to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since javascript is asynchronous, all of your animations are running at the same time. Therefore, your `$('#vitesse').val()` is the same value in all 4 of those calls as soon as the  function is called. You can work around that by using a callback function in your animate calls.

```
var txtBox = $('#vitesse'),
    camion = $('#camion');

camion.animate({ top: 120, left: 180}, txtBox.val(), function() {
    camion.animate({ top: 180, left: 180 }, txtBox.val(), function() {
        // keep going or write this recursively.
    });
});
```